# Dual boot install, issue with select a boot disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a desktop with a 256GB SSD and 1TB HDD. It came preinstalled with Windows10. I am trying to make it a dual boot.

I created a partition each in SSD(40GB for /) and HDD(250GB for /home). Plugged in the USB ubuntu installer and it guided me to the Storage configuration - custom option. Attached is the partition information.

[Partition information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnVCC.jpg)

Tried a few of these below:

1. It does not let me continue without selecting a boot disk.
2. I am not able to select the ESP partition of Windows as boot disk.
3. I am not able to use a new 512MB partition in vfat format as a boot disk. Instructed to format it in ext4 and mount as /boot. The 'Select a boot disk' does not go away.

Please help on how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Do not confuse an ESP - efi system partition which must be FAT32 and is used by UEFI for booting with a Linux /boot partition which must be a Linux format. Most desktops do not need a separate /boot partition, but some server or LVM type installs may want or need it.Just be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode as that is then how it installs. And with Ubuntu it automatically uses an existing ESP on first drive.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you. Couple of things I had to do: One, change to CSM disabled in BIOS setting. Second, make the USB installer UEFI bootable instead of MBR.